# When to trigger a scroll after images load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

Using Quasar framework I have multiple children and need to scroll to a certain child after loading the page. I can do so by setting a delay using `setTimeout` but I would prefer a better/fail-proof solution.

My current approach is to wait for all children to mount (and use `nextTick`) and thought it should be ready for the scroll, but apparently not. Alternatively I can wait for all images to be loaded (as `QImg` has a `@load` [event](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/img#QImg-API)), but that is really late, since manually I can already trigger a scroll while image boxes are already rendered but still loading.

What is the best way to trigger at 'the earliest possible moment'?

Point-panel (parent):

```
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  template: `
    <div id="point-panel" class="map-overlay column scroll">
      <small-cards
        @hook:mounted="cardsAreReady(cardIndex, picArray.length)"
        v-for="(point, cardIndex) in picArray"
        :key="cardIndex"
        :point-object="point"
        :card-index="cardIndex"
      />
      <q-btn
        @click.native="scrollToCenter"
        fab
        ripple
        class="fixed"
        size="10px"
        color="black"
        label="scroll"
        style="right: 18px; bottom: 120px"
      />
    </div>
  `,

  data: function () {
    return {
      selectedPointIndex: 6,
      picArray: ['https://image1', 'https://image2', 'https://image_etc.']
    }
  },

  methods: {
    notify (msg) {
      this.$q.notify(msg)
    },
    cardsAreReady (cardIndex, total) {
      console.log('one ready.......', `${cardIndex} ...and total ${total}`)
      const that = this
      if (cardIndex + 1 === total) {
        console.log('....all cards MOUNTED!', cardIndex)
        setTimeout(() => {
          that.$nextTick(() => {
            console.log('..........trigger scroll NOW!')
            that.scrollToCenter()
          })
        }, 0)
      }
    },
    scrollToCenter () {
      const that = this
      console.log('..........cardIndex: ', that.selectedPointIndex)
      that.notify('scroll triggered!')

      function scrollFunction () {
        const element = document.getElementsByClassName(
          that.selectedPointIndex.toString()
        )
        const target = document.getElementById('point-panel')
        const iW = window.innerWidth
        const iH = window.innerHeight
        const myOffset = element[0].offsetLeft
        Quasar.utils.scroll.setHorizontalScrollPosition(target, myOffset, 0)
      }
      setTimeout(() => scrollFunction(), 0)
    }
  }
})
```

Images/small-cards (children):

```
Vue.component('small-cards', {
  props: {
    pointObject: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    cardIndex: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0
    }
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      selectedPointIndex: 6
    }
  },

  methods: {
    reportError (event) {
      console.log(`${event.name}: ${event.message}`)
    },
  },

  template: `
    <div
      class="mycard"
      :class="{
        'active': cardIndex === selectedPointIndex,
        [cardIndex]: true
      }"
    >
      <q-img
        :src="pointObject"
        spinner-size="30px"
        style="background-color: rgba(255, 225, 215, 0.4)"
        @error="reportError"
      />
    </div>
  `
})
```

Here you can find a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/zmgp9vdL/205/) showing the issue. I have added a scroll button to show that after loading you can trigger a scroll successfully (the 6th picture, i.e. 'the Tiger' is scrolled to the bottom-left corner).

EDIT: To give the question somewhat more direction: The problem is that if `scroll` is triggered to soon the DOM is not yet rendered and thus the distance to scroll can not yet be determined. But I would think that after 
`mount` the Dom should be determined?! So why does current approach not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT/NEW ANSWER:***

I was finally able to get this to work... Here is what I had to do to fix it:

- ***~EDIT~*** adding `$nextTick` (as OP suggested) makes this a lot more consistent! OP was able to get this working sans a wrapper component as well
- The `small-cards` component now `emits` an event when the image is done loading
- Created a "wrapper" for the `small-cards` component called `small-cards-wrapper`
- This "wrapper" has 2 `props`: 1) `items`, an array of image sources 2) `scrollToIndex`, the index number you would like to scroll to at `mount`
- The `small-cards-wrapper` component will pick up on the emitted event (from `small-cards` component[s]) and check to see if it is the index you want to scroll to - if it is, we scroll to it..
- **Essentially, we wait for the image to load before trying to scroll to it..**

I'm sure you will be able to see what I changed after reviewing the code, but if you have any questions just let me know!

[[***NEWEST*** JSFiddle (with `$nextTick`)]](https://jsfiddle.net/6m59w7tL/)

[[***UPDATED*** JSFiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/ouswdea1/3/)

---

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

I triggered the `scrollToCenter()` method during `mount`, as well as removed the `hook.mounted` logic from the template..

I have commented the above changes that were made within the code so you can see exactly what I did..

If you do not want the scroll to occur 2 seconds from mount, you can remove the `setTimeout` - this was done to show how it scrolls after loading (gives you time to see it happen)..

Is this what you are looking for?

---

---

```js
Vue.component('small-cards', {
  props: {
    pointObject: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    cardIndex: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0
    },
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedPointIndex: 6
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reportError(event) {
      console.log(`${event.name}: ${event.message}`);
    },
    handleLoad() {
      this.$emit('loaded-card', true);
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div class="mycard" :class="{[cardIndex]: true}">
    <q-img :src="pointObject"
     @load="handleLoad"
      spinner-size="30px"
      style="background-color: rgba(255, 225, 215, 0.4)"
     @error="reportError">
    </q-img>
  </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('small-cards-wrapper', {
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    scrollToIndex: {
      type: Number,
      required: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    isLoaded(x) {
      if (Number(x) === Number(this.scrollToIndex)) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          const element = document.getElementsByClassName(x.toString())
          const target = document.getElementById('point-panel')
          const iW = window.innerWidth
          const iH = window.innerHeight
          const myOffset = element[0].offsetLeft
          Quasar.utils.scroll.setHorizontalScrollPosition(target, myOffset, 0)
          this.$q.notify("Scroll Triggered!");        
        })
      }
    }
  },
  template: `
 <div id="point-panel" class='map-overlay column scroll'>   
   <small-cards
     v-for='(point, cardIndex) in items'
      :key="cardIndex"
      :point-object="point"
      :card-index="cardIndex"
      @loaded-card="isLoaded(cardIndex)"
    ></small-cards>
  </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      selectedPointIndex: 6,
      picArray: ["https://images.takeshape.io/86ce9525-f5f2-4e97-81ba-54e8ce933da7/dev/144069dc-7390-4022-aa0f-abba022d3a2f/spec.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat", "https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/prescribed_burn_oregon.jpg?crop=0,120,5760,3600&wid=1640&hei=1025&scl=3.5121951219512195", "https://orig11.deviantart.net/1062/f/2015/315/9/6/abstract__7_by_thejsyve1-d9gciwk.jpg", "https://natureconservancy-h.assetsadobe.com/is/image/content/dam/tnc/nature/en/photos/Brown_County_Hills_Leonetti.jpg?crop=33,0,1192,656&wid=4000&hei=2200&scl=0.29818181818181816", "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/galleries/travel/destinations/northamerica/usa/US%20national%20parks/AP84847745_Yosemite_General-xlarge.jpg", "https://dehayf5mhw1h7.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/183/2016/09/15173325/Brown_County_Indiana_Estados_Unidos_2012-10-14_DD_10.jpg", "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/19/e9/58/19e9581dbdc756a2dbbb38ae39a3419c.jpg", "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/green-1072828_960_720.jpg", "https://www.alwareness.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Bomen-Bos.jpg", "https://www.campz.be/info/wp-content/uploads/header-pic-mountain.jpeg", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSUzRyiSPfzeIogLgkY1P8ugrvzls23SMhOcJi7vmUfCe4r1nKa", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg", "https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5720/22076039308_4e2fc21c5f_o.jpg"]
    }
  },
  template: `
 <div>
   <h4>Scroll now occurs on 'mount'</h4>
    <small-cards-wrapper 
      :items="picArray" 
      :scroll-to-index="selectedPointIndex"
    ></small-cards-wrapper>
  </div>
  `,
})
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.map-overlay {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 30vh;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 150, 0.3);
  font: 'Abel', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  color: #8e3433;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row,
.column,
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

html,
body,
#q-app {
  width: 100%;
  direction: ltr;
}

.mycard {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 47vw;
  margin: 3px 0 9px 2vw;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/quasar-extras@2.0.9/material-icons/material-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@^1.0.0-beta.0/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@^1.0.0-beta.0/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="q-app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there a better solution then this? When I set your `setTimeout` to 0 the scroll does not work anymore, so this is not really what I am looking for as now I have to guess what is a delay that will always work (also when I have a substantial number of images etc.). So I am looking for an event that says 'now the Dom is ready and you can trigger your scroll'.

Comment: I was heading in the same direction (I mean using the `@load` event) which can also be done without the wrapper. I first thought it was solved, but no... your and my solution are showing one picture (the woods) before the one it should (the tiger)...!! Compare my fiddle when mounting on load and when pressing the button. Button triggers exact same function but in button case the dom is ready I think... So not quite solved yet I'm afraid. Still in the woods!! [Relevant new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/hp13j6qw/114/)

Comment: I've added a `nextTick` and then I think [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/musicformellons/fmthaw42/4/) as should! Can you maybe update the answer, so I can approve?

Comment: So mine does in fact work, but sometimes it takes a little bit to kick in.. This is because that 'Tiger photo' seems to take longer to load.. The click event doesn't fire until the 'Tiger photo' is fully loaded.. If you wait 20 seconds or so, the click event will eventually fire.  That is the ultimate issue here - adding `nextTick` seems to have no effect.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue - each time I load this page it triggers the scroll event once the tiger picture is loaded..

Comment: @musicformellons - I take that back - looks like adding `$nextTick` makes this a lot more consistent and responsive.. I have updated my answer :)  Glad you got this working!! It was a nice challenge.